# Akoya P6643 Display distorted image when changing angle / Inspiron Display only visible with Torch

Tags: laptop, display, dell-inspiron, repair, laptop-display

My used bought laptop has a screen issue:
When moving the display e.g. changing the angle, I would get some distorted image.

I had this exact problem with my Inpsiron N5030 and fixed it by reattaching the LCD-Cable from the mainboard to the display. That worked out until my whole Screen went almost dead from one second to the next. I assume its a fried Backlight Inverter or such... An replacement LCD is 50 bucks... Thats why I purchased this thing, wich sadly turned out to have the same issue from beginning. Both laptops would only behave normal on certain angles. 
Since I fear that this laptop could possibly die too, but I want to get rid of these nasty screen bugs, my question is the following:
I alread broke some minor plastic parts off when trying to get the screen bezel off.
I suppose that the issue is, similar to my old laptop, the connector on the LCD not being inserted correctly or a broken cable

Is there a chance to fix my Dell Inspiron N5030 for less then the Price of 20 dollars?
And how can i get the screen bezel off of my akoya Modell? The plastic on the bottom corners just wont go off! And I dont want to break it :(

Sincerly 
Niklas

Answer (score 0):

If the screen works properly at some angles but not others, it's almost certainly a connection problem.  A ribbon cable is a good bet, but it could also be something like a bad solder joint.  If two of the same model have had the same problem, it sounds like a design issue.

re: $20, it's a safe bet that you can't get any professional repair of anything for that amount.  If you are doing the work yourself, there's no way for us to know.  If it's a loose ribbon cable, it might cost nothing.  A ribbon cable with a fractured trace would be cheap to replace.  If you need to start replacing parts, it depends on the part and where you get it.  If you can salvage what you need from another discarded or 2nd-hand unit, it could be cheap.

As far as how to get the bezel off, sometimes the catches are easy enough to locate and sometimes not.  Search for YouTube videos, or search for a replacement bezel.  Pictures of the bezel may indicate the catch locations (and if you break it, you will have a source for replacement).

Comment: it are two different models. I just had bad luck... I did replace the cable on the old one on my own already for like 8 eur for a replacement cable. I am no expert in electronics and cant locate where the Inverter issue iss coming from... i barely know how to use a multimeter.

Comment: @insertRandomName, it sounds like the question actually covers a number of different issues, so the situation isn't clear.  It will be easier for people to answer if you post a separate question for each issue.